# Ruby on Rails concatenate key & values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    "name_printed_on_badge": "John",
    "is_active": "Yes",
    "is_valid": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "name_printed_on_badge": "John",
    "is_active": "Yes",
    "is_valid": "No"
  }
]
```

I want to learn how to concatenate each key and value pair and return an array in the output format below:

```
[
  [
    "name_printed_on_badge: John",
    "is_active: Yes",
    "is_valid: Yes"
  ],
  [
    "name_printed_on_badge: John",
    "is_active: Yes",
    "is_valid: No"
  ]
]
```

Comment: The two arrays look the same to me. What do you want the final result to be?

Comment: final result would not contain hashes in array, instead it will be an array of arrays

Comment: Thanks. I missed that subtle difference. I suggest using `map` to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
array = [
  {
    "name_printed_on_badge": "John",
    "is_active": "Yes",
    "is_valid": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "name_printed_on_badge": "John",
    "is_active": "Yes",
    "is_valid": "No"
  }
]

array.map do |hash| 
  hash.map { |key, value| "#{key}: #{value}" }
end
# [["name_printed_on_badge: John", "is_active: Yes", "is_valid: Yes"], ["name_printed_on_badge: John", "is_active: Yes", "is_valid: No"]]
```

Comment: thank you, looks like I need to spend a day or two on exploring hash and arrays in ruby